# How to update some rows in a partitioned table in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I need to update some rows in a partitioned table by date, with a   ranges of  dates and i don't know how to do it?

Comment: Hi, what type of file you associated with the table: avro,parquet,orc?

Comment: how do you identify those rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dynamic partitioning you can overwrite partitions which is necessary to update. Use case statement to check for rows to be modified and to set values, like in this template:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert overwrite table table_name partition (partition_column)

select col1, 
       col2,
       case when col1='record to be updated' then 'new value' else col3 end as col3,
       ...
       colN,
       partition_column --partition_column should be the last
from table_name 
where ...--partition predicate here
```